# Comparing dates not working in java

Tags: java

```
 public static void main(String [] args){
    String date = "01/08/2017";

    Date todaydate = new Date();

    SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/mm/yyyy");
    try {
        Date expiry = myFormat.parse(date);

        if(expiry.compareTo(todaydate) >0){
            System.out.println("false");
        }

        else{
            System.out.println("true");
        }
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am comparing date `01/08/2017` to current date. It should return false. However, it is returning true, even if I use `isAfter` in the `if` condition.

Comment: Your date format is wrong. Use `dd/MM/yyyy` instead of `dd/mm/yyyy`. Lower-case `mm` means **minutes**, not months. See the [API docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) of `SimpleDateFormat`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do the trick

```
SimpleDateFormat myFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Comment: Yes. Now it`s working.

Comment: @Muzogeek Please accept the answer, if your problem is resolved :-)

Answer (score 1):

The value 0 if the argument is a string lexicographically equal to this string; a value less than 0 if the argument is a string lexicographically greater than this string; and a value greater than 0 if the argument is a string lexicographically less than this string.

you need to change the condition

```
 if(expiry.compareTo(todaydate) <0)
```

Go to this link n see the methods of the dates 
      https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/date_compareto.htm

Comment: Talking about lexical ordering of Strings is somewhat confusing when we are comparing Dates...

Answer (score 1):

besides the format, `compareTo()` is returning true, always that the date is after the argument, which is right. If the dates where equals it would return 0.

Check the docs: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#compareTo%28java.util.Date%29